# How to create a stripplot with multiple subplots

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, subplot, stripplot

This is my example data

```
data = {'pro1': [1, 1, 1, 0],
        'pro2': [0, 1, 1, 1],
        'pro3': [0, 1, 0, 1],
        'pro4': [0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to make striplot in seaborn like this (but actually wrong when running):

```
sns.stripplot(x=['pro1', 'pro2', 'pro3'], y='pro4', data=df)
```

This is my alternative code:

```
# Create a figure with two subplots that share the y-axis
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 4), sharey=True)

# List of column names
l = ['pro1', 'pro2', 'pro3', 'pro4']

# Subplot 1: Positive values
df1 = df.copy(deep=True)
for i in l:
    # Set values to pro4 only when the corresponding pro1, pro2, pro3 is 1
    df1[i] = df1.apply(lambda row: row['pro4'] if row[i] == 1 else None, axis=1)
df1.drop(['pro4'], axis=1, inplace=True)
sns.stripplot(data=df1, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('Positive Values')  # Add a title to the subplot

# Subplot 2: Zero values
df1 = df.copy(deep=True)
for i in l:
    # Set values to pro4 only when the corresponding pro1, pro2, pro3 is 0
    df1[i] = df1.apply(lambda row: row['pro4'] if row[i] == 0 else None, axis=1)
df1.drop(['pro4'], axis=1, inplace=True)
sns.stripplot(data=df1, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('Zero Values')  # Add a title to the subplot

# Show the plots
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]
My questions are: "is there any more simple way to do for the same result like below?"

```
sns.stripplot(x=['pro1', 'pro2', 'pro3'], y='pro4', hue = [0,1], data=df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest is to [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) and [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.catplot(df.melt('pro4'), x='variable', y='pro4', 
            hue='variable', col='value',
            kind='strip')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is a great simple solution for my issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ah yes, sns.catplot is the best solution.  Great solution, @mozway!  +1